# Executing a string without eval or is eval ok to use here?

Tags: javascript, eval

Is there a better way of executing the string "getData" without eval or eval a good option in this case since what is being evaluated is not user generated?

```
object.myMainObject(Marcus)

object = {
    Data = {
        Marcus : function(){
            alert('marcus function')
        },
        James : function(){
            alert('james function')
        }
    }

    myMainObject : function(string){
        getData = "object.Data." + string + "()"

        eval(getData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. We get that question at least once a week. I wonder where all the javascript beginners some from, and why they aren't taught such important fundamentals as the object <-> hash map isomorphism early on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval` is *completely unnecessary* for this case, just use the *bracket notation* to access the *dynamically* named property:

```
var object = {
    Data : {
        Marcus : function(){
            alert('marcus function');
        },
        James : function(){
            alert('james function');
        }
    }

    myMainObject : function(string){
        var getData = object.Data[string]();
    }
};

object.myMainObject("Marcus"); // 'marcus function'
```

Notes:

- There were some syntax errors in the way you were defining `object` (you were using `=`, instead of `:` ).
- You weren't using the `var` statement to declare `object` nor `getData`, please, when declaring variables, use the `var` statement, otherwise, they will end up as properties of the global object.
- As a safety measure, you could check if the member that's being accessed is actually a function before calling it, e.g.:

  ```
  //...
  var getData;
  if (typeof object.Data[string] == 'function') {
     getData = object.Data[string]();
  }
  //...
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better way.  Use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) to access an object's properties by name:

```
object.Data[string]();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not ok to eval it.

`getData = object.Data[string]()`

Answer (score -1):

It's ok to eval it. Although I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not ok to eval it (edit: not my downvote though). Think `string == "x; alert('har har')//"`. Especially since there's an eval-free way that works much better and is actually easier to type and read.

Comment: It appears that he wants to run a function by passing in a string which is the name of the function. :P

Comment: Yeah, I definitely didn't understand what was going on. Still, I'll leave my answer as a warning to others!